# Reporting Server GetPolicies call extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We are invoking getpolicies followed by setpolicies method of reporting server (SSRS) but, it is extremely slow and since the getpolicies (followed by setpolicies) is being called multiple times (that is the business need) the total elapsed time (over one hour) is significantly high and is impacting functionality of application

Can you please help and provide some indicators on what can be done to improve the performance.

Comment: Take a look at the execution log (see below article) and examine where is the report taking more time: data retrieval, processing or rendering? 
Refer - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159110.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Its not the report per se which is taking time. Getpolicies, setpolicies are API calls exposed by reporting service which is taking time. Any insight regarding it will be helpful.